# Learning a smooth, real-valued non-parametric probability distribution

Tags: neural-networks, regularization, loss-functions

I would like to train a neural network to learn a probability distribution. (Density estimation of a model-independent "true" probability density function of a given output.) That is, I have a set of training examples where a real-valued output is drawn from a certain (unknown, non-parametric) probability distribution, conditioned on a given set of input features. Given the set of input features of an unknown, I would like the neural network to output information about the probability distribution (for that set of input features), such that I could potentially do further processing on it. (e.g. randomly sample from it; note that I don't just want the neural network to predict the optimal expected value of the output, but rather the full probability density function).

Given that there's a known range and effective minimum "resolution" of the output value (e.g. a difference of 1 unit is meaningful, but a difference of 0.1 unit is not), my general thoughts are to discretize the output space, then effectively do a multi-class classification of each of the output value bins, using softmax to normalize to probabilities. My understanding of the standard multiclass classification training process is that the predicted outputs should (ideally) converge to the underlying probability distribution, conditioned on the input features. (Please correct me if I'm wrong.)

The hangup I have with the process is there's no ordinal coordination between the various bins. That is, each bin is considered independently of the others in such a multiclass classification process, such that the probability of bin 5 and 6 are no more correlated than bins 5 and 25. Due to the nature of the problem, I would expect there to be some correlation/smoothing of probability values at scales larger than that of the "resolution". (The probability density function is smooth and continuous, without major swings.)

I'm wondering if there's any accepted loss functions or regularization procedures which would potentially help impose such a constraint in the functional form of the predicted probability distribution. (Or if there's an alternate formulation of the training which means my initial discretization idea is misguided.) I could probably *ad hoc* an additional loss term, but I was wondering if there might be something with a more well-supported theoretical justification.

Comment: I can't vouch for it's usefulness in your application, but lookup ordinal regression/classification, which would deal with the ordering issue

Comment: Also, complementing the answer mentioning GANs and VAEs, Flow-based models can be used to learn distributions, since they are bijective

Answer (score 2):

It's not that clear what you are actually looking for, if a classifier or a density estimator, but I think you are looking for a conditional variational autoencoder, or a conditional GAN.

A cVAE is a neural network which takes in input a sample from your distribution, maps it to a known distribution (and a second conditional distribution), and then back to the original sample.

Doing that, at the end you can sample in the latent dimension, which distribution is known, and you get samples from your distribution.

Check this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.04405.pdf for cVAE and this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.1784.pdf for cGAN

Comment: I'm looking for a density estimator. And I'm looking for estimating a (process-independent) non-parametric "true" density in the "output" space, rather than a imposed parametric density in some arbitrary transformed latent space (as a VAE does). -- My question resolves around how best to impose smoothness/continuity properties in the learned density estimate (which is to be predicted with a neural network due to other considerations).

Comment: @R.M. the imposed is just a proxy to allow you to sample from an unknown distribution, is not an "assumption on the underlying distribution"